# Relative path in web config

Tags: c#, .net, path, web-config, relative-path

How can I have a relative path in the web.config file. This value is not in the connection string so I cannot use |DataDirectory| (I think), so what can I do?

Comment: I thinnk you mean application-specific url. relative url means relative to the directory in which you currently reside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the relative path for?

Are you talking about a physical directory path or a url path?

Edit:

I needed to do something similar for one of my projects. I needed to locate a config file that was stored in a certain folder. While the web.config file itself does not provide anything special for this, you can take a path from the web.config file and convert it to an app-relative path.

Request.ApplicationPath gets you the base directory of the web application. YOu can append the relative path to this and give it to whatever needs it.

Also see [this blog post by Rick Strahl](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/269.aspx) for other interesting directories that may help you.

You could then append the relatvie path to

Comment: I want to use the equivalent of ~/App_Data/Foobar.xml on whatever box I load it onto.

Comment: That link to Rick Strahl's website is invalid.